# Algorithm to make object move from a Point A to a Point B in a certain speed

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Okay, I actually thought this would be easy to do using trigonometry. This is where I've got to:

```
moveTowardsPoint = function(point1, point2, speed) {
    let vector, vLength, factor, newX, newY;

    vector = pointMakeVector(point1, point2);
    vLength = length(vector);

    if (vLength == 0) {
        return point1;
    }

    factor = speed/vLength;

    newX = point1.x + factor*vector.x;
    newY = point1.y + factor*vector.y;
    
    return {x: Math.round(newX), y: Math.round(newY)};
}

pointMakeVector = function(point1, point2) {
    let xDist, yDist;

    xDist = point2.x - point1.x;
    yDist = point2.y - point1.y;

    return {x: xDist, y: yDist};
}

length = function(vector) {
    return Math.sqrt(vector.x*vector.x + vector.y*vector.y);
}
```

The thing is: this algorithm works fine until the part that I need to round the values in the returned object. But rounding the x and y position, I get a really bad approximation for a straight line as the object moves. Any way to fix it? Or maybe a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the rounding because this introduces precision errors. Imagine you have two points `p0(0, 0)` and `p1(200, 400)` and using `speed` you project `p0'` and get `(0.3, 0.6)`. Rounding will round the point to `(0, 1)` causing the vector to travel vertically until the vectors horizontal position offsets the rounding biases causing the vector to change direction. The error term becomes smaller as `p0` gets closer to `p1` but it could be minimized by just not rounding. It might be easier to see an illustration of the errors. I am not clearing the canvas so that you can see some interesting patterns that emerge from rounding (full page mode, looks cooler).

```js
const color = () => {
  const b = () => ((Math.random() * 256) | 0);
  
  return `rgba(${b()}, ${b()}, ${b()}, .5)`
};

const moveTowardsPoint = (point1, point2, speed) => {
  let vector, vLength, factor, newX, newY;

  vector = pointMakeVector(point1, point2);
  vLength = length(vector);

  if (vLength == 0) {
    return point1;
  }

  factor = speed / vLength;

  newX = point1.x + factor * vector.x;
  newY = point1.y + factor * vector.y;

  return {
    x: Math.round(newX),
    y: Math.round(newY)
  };
}

const pointMakeVector = (point1, point2) => {
  let xDist, yDist;

  xDist = point2.x - point1.x;
  yDist = point2.y - point1.y;

  return {
    x: xDist,
    y: yDist
  };
}

const length = (vector) => {
  return Math.sqrt(vector.x * vector.x + vector.y * vector.y);
}

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const width = canvas.width;
const height = canvas.height;

let p0 = {
  x: Math.random() * width,
  y: Math.random() * height
};

let p1 = {
  x: width / 2,
  y: height / 2
}

let c = color();

const step = () => {
  p0 = moveTowardsPoint(p0, p1, 1);

  if (p0.x === p1.x && p0.y === p1.y) {
    c = color();
    p0 = {
      x: Math.random() * width,
      y: Math.random() * height
    };
  }
  
  context.strokeStyle = c;
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(p0.x, p0.y, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  context.stroke();

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(p1.x, p1.y, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  context.stroke();

  requestAnimationFrame(step);
};

step();
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

I think what you are trying to do is create positions so that you can draw them without sub pixeling or whatever. What you should do is keep your simulations in high precision and round/truncate the coordinates as you draw

```js
const color = () => {
  const b = () => ((Math.random() * 256) | 0);
  
  return `rgba(${b()}, ${b()}, ${b()}, .5)`
};

const moveTowardsPoint = (point1, point2, speed) => {
  let vector, vLength, factor, newX, newY;

  vector = pointMakeVector(point1, point2);
  vLength = length(vector);

  if (vLength == 0) {
    return point1;
  }

  factor = speed / vLength;

  newX = point1.x + factor * vector.x;
  newY = point1.y + factor * vector.y;

  return {
    x: newX,
    y: newY
  };
}

const pointMakeVector = (point1, point2) => {
  let xDist, yDist;

  xDist = point2.x - point1.x;
  yDist = point2.y - point1.y;

  return {
    x: xDist,
    y: yDist
  };
}

const length = (vector) => {
  return Math.sqrt(vector.x * vector.x + vector.y * vector.y);
}

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const width = canvas.width;
const height = canvas.height;

let p0 = {
  x: Math.random() * width,
  y: Math.random() * height
};

let p1 = {
  x: width / 2,
  y: height / 2
}

let c = color();

const step = () => {
  p0 = moveTowardsPoint(p0, p1, 1);
 
  if (Math.abs(p0.x - p1.x) < 0.5 && Math.abs(p0.y - p1.y) < 0.5) {
    c = color();
    p0 = {
      x: Math.random() * width,
      y: Math.random() * height
    };
  }
  
  context.strokeStyle = c;
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(Math.round(p0.x), Math.round(p0.y), 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  context.stroke();

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(Math.round(p1.x), Math.round(p1.y), 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  context.stroke();

  requestAnimationFrame(step);
};

step();
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```